# The mediaplayer is released in onStop() if the buffering time is too long in PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK mode

Tags: android

I am developing a streaming video application.

MediaPlayer are released in 'onStop()' method.

The problem is that if the init/buff time is too long, 'PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK' mode is entered but 'onStop()' call is made before showing the video. The CPU is running but the MediaPlayer is released and the video does not end the process of buffering and don't start again.

If the video buffering ends and video starts before entering 'onStop()' no problem. (for example on Good net connection)

One solution is set Power Save to 'FULL_WAKE_LOCK' mode. It's works fine because 'onStop' are not executed until the user exits the application. But if the user press the power button video stops because the MediaPlayer is destroyed and don't restart again.

Is there any other solution?

The Relevant Code:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

(...)

/**
 * Trigger when Activity is created
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onCreate");

    (...)

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "my_wake");


    (...)


    mVideoSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);


    // Inicializa Video
    initSurfaceView();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onStart");
    wl.acquire();
    Log.i(TAG,"Adquire WakeLock");
}   

/**
 * Init Video Surface View
 */
private void initSurfaceView() {
    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
    mVideoSurfaceViewHolder = mVideoSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mVideoSurfaceViewHolder.addCallback(mSurfaceHolderCallback);
    mVideoSurfaceView.setFocusable(true);
    mVideoSurfaceView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mVideoSurfaceView.requestFocus();
}


/**
 * Start play video operations
 * @param url Video Streming URL
 */
private void playVideo(String url) {
    doCleanUp();
    try {
        // Create a new media player and set the listeners
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(mOnVideoSizeChangedListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletionListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mOnBufferingUpdateListener);
        //mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mVideoPath2);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mVideoSurfaceViewHolder);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

/**
 * Vars clean up
 */
private void doCleanUp() {
    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
}

/**
 * Release Media Player
 */
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }

}


MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener = 
    new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");

            if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }

        }

};

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onStop");
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
    wl.release();
}   
/**
 * Activity destroyed
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onDestroy");
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}



}
```

Comment: What did you expect? You are release 'MediaPlayer' when calling 'onStop()'.
If you don't want stop prepare after 'onStop()' you should provide it in code.

Comment: If I don't release in onStop() work fine but not good practice...I want to use 'PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK' because in that mode: If the user presses the power button, then the screen will be turned off but the CPU will be kept on until all partial wake locks have been released and Video will going on

Comment: Well. I think I will use 'FULL_WAKE_LOCK' and if the user presses the button MediaPlayer will released and I will create other in the onStart method. The downside of this is that there will be a delay, buffering again etc

Answer (score 0):

One solution: (but press power button makes stop video and re-buffering again)

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

    (...)

    /**
    * Trigger when Activity is created
    */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onCreate");

        (...)

         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "my_wake");

         (...)


         mVideoSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);


         // Inicializa Video
        initSurfaceView();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onStart");
        wl.acquire();
        Log.i(TAG,"Adquire WakeLock");
        if (mChannel!=null){
            playVideo(mChannel.getUrl());  //RESTART MEDIAPLAYER AGAIN
        } 
    }   

    /**
    * Init Video Surface View
    */
    private void initSurfaceView() {
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mVideoSurfaceViewHolder = mVideoSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mVideoSurfaceViewHolder.addCallback(mSurfaceHolderCallback);
        mVideoSurfaceView.setFocusable(true);
        mVideoSurfaceView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mVideoSurfaceView.requestFocus();
    }


     /**
     * Start play video operations
     * @param url Video Streming URL
     */
     private void playVideo(String url) {
         doCleanUp();
         try {
             // Create a new media player and set the listeners
             mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
             mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK);
             mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);
             mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(mOnVideoSizeChangedListener);
             mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletionListener);
             mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mOnBufferingUpdateListener);
             //mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mVideoPath2);
             mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
             mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mVideoSurfaceViewHolder);
             mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
             mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
             mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
         }
    }

    /**
    * Vars clean up
    */
    private void doCleanUp() {
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    }

    /**
    * Release Media Player
    */
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
              mMediaPlayer.release();
              mMediaPlayer = null;
        }

    }


    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener = 
        new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");

                     if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed) {
                         mediaPlayer.start();
                     }

            }

    };

         @Override
         protected void onStop() {
             super.onStop();
             Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onStop");
             releaseMediaPlayer();
             doCleanUp();
             wl.release();
         }  
     /**
     * Activity destroyed
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onDestroy");
         releaseMediaPlayer();
         doCleanUp();
     }



}
```

Other solution (not good). Works fine, if user press power button video don't stop playing only sound. If user press back botton to finish Video stop but MediaPlayer not release (Not good solution) Problems with some codecs (Maybe some native MediaPlayer instances will be alive).

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

    (...)

    /**
    * Trigger when Activity is created
    */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onCreate");

        (...)

         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "my_wake");

         (...)


         mVideoSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);


         // Inicializa Video
        initSurfaceView();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onStart");
        wl.acquire();
        Log.i(TAG,"Adquire WakeLock");

    }   

    /**
    * Init Video Surface View
    */
    private void initSurfaceView() {
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mVideoSurfaceViewHolder = mVideoSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mVideoSurfaceViewHolder.addCallback(mSurfaceHolderCallback);
        mVideoSurfaceView.setFocusable(true);
        mVideoSurfaceView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mVideoSurfaceView.requestFocus();
    }


     /**
     * Start play video operations
     * @param url Video Streming URL
     */
     private void playVideo(String url) {
         doCleanUp();
         try {
             // Create a new media player and set the listeners
             mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
             mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
             mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);
             mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(mOnVideoSizeChangedListener);
             mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletionListener);
             mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mOnBufferingUpdateListener);
             //mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mVideoPath2);
             mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
             mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mVideoSurfaceViewHolder);
             mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
             mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
             mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
         }
    }

    /**
    * Vars clean up
    */
    private void doCleanUp() {
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    }

    /**
    * Release Media Player
    */
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
              mMediaPlayer.release();
              mMediaPlayer = null;
        }

    }


    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener = 
        new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");

                     if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed) {
                         mediaPlayer.start();
                     }

            }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onStop");
        wl.release();
    }   

     /**
     * Activity destroyed
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         Log.i(TAG,"VideoActivity - onDestroy");
         releaseMediaPlayer();
         doCleanUp();
     }



}
```